# Insert a toolbar div to a page and push the body down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to inject a toolbar to a body when a button is clicked. It should be fixed at the top and should remain there even when the user scrolls down. I'm having some problems moving the body down because the toolbar covers some of the body content and leaves a blank space at the top. Here is my code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <button onclick="inject()">Inject</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#customToolbar1234 {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important; 
    height: 35px;
    border: 0 !important;
    background: #e3e3e3 !important;
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```

JS

```
function inject() {

    var sg_div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'customToolbar1234').addClass('selectorgadget_bottom').addClass('selectorgadget_ignore');
    $('body').append(sg_div);

    var first_button = $('<input type="button" value="0"/>');
    sg_div.append(first_button);


    $('body').css({
        'transform': 'translateY(35px)',
        'transition': 'transform 0.4s ease'
    });
}
```

In the JS code, If I append the div to html tag instead of body, then the code works fine but I don't want to add div outside of the body tag. I don't want to use an iframe either, just a div. How would I do this? Here is a [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/qewoqexaqe/1/edit?html,css,js,output) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, fixed the code. You had applied a wrong CSS on body tag using your javascript. The change is on Javascript only

```js
function inject() {

 //var url = chrome.extension.getURL('toolbar.html');

    var sg_div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'customToolbar1234').addClass('selectorgadget_bottom').addClass('selectorgadget_ignore');
    $('body').append(sg_div);

    var first_button = $('<input type="button" value="0"/>');
    sg_div.append(first_button);


 $('body').css({
     'padding-top':'35px',
     'transition': 'transform 0.4s ease'
 });


 
}
```

```css
#customToolbar1234 {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important; 
    height: 35px;
    border: 0 !important;
    background: #e3e3e3 !important;
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <button onclick="inject()">Inject</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use padding-top on the body? Also if you don't have a special reason for it, don't add css directly in the js. Instead apply a class and target that in css. Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kibahiduki/1/edit?html,css,js,output).